# How to adjust Joomla site position?

Tags: joomla-2.5, templates, css

I want to adjust (align) the content (body) of my Joomla site as it's shown on the images attached to this question. There're picture 1 and picture 2. I want it to be like on a picture 1. Basically, I want to decrease spacing above the top horizontal main menu.[image]

[image]
**UPDATE**
The big spacing above my upper horizontal main menu was due to some "gkToolbar", which is probably unnecessary from what I was told. After this adjustment, I had 10px spacing above and below upper horizontal main menu. But I still don't know how to change (lessen) the upper space (10px). I've got J 2.5 and MyStore template.

```
#gkToolbar {
display: none; } body { margin: 0 !important;
/* color: #6C6459;
height: 25px;
margin: 20px 0 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 10px 0 0; */
}

#gkMenuWrap {
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You can do this adjusts in css template file. If you send me a link from your site its possible i can help you.

Comment: This question is difficult to answer as it is. Please provide a link to your site or provide the relevant CSS.

Comment: Or at least let us know what template you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Category → article → select the category → then give the article tittle → select one image and insert into the article working space.
Now select the image tools → source code → style='float :left; padding-right: 10px;”
press save then choose the article image → insert/edit image → select the option like dimensions,alignment,margin,border.
The above mentioned settings are available in the image manager.

Set the horizontal menu space:
login into joomla
In the top menu, click Extensions and then click Module Manager. 
Select the main menu → edit → advanced options. 
Choose menu class suffix → type nav-pills.
Important:before typing nav-pills give one space

Answer (score 0):

Go to the templates section of your administrator section. Make sure your on the styles section then click the template name on the right side of the template you are using.

The gktoolbar might be included with your tempalte. If you do not like it you can possible remove it from the template if you know how.

Most templates I have seen have a custom css file or a override css file to allow for changes to the template, which you can add on this portion of the page within the css folder. If a file is not provided you can make one. Within the templates index.php you should find the code to either remove the toolbar ,this may cause errors, or you should be able to find a place if it is not there do add an override css file.

In my template I add the below for overrides later.

This is the templates css file.

```
$doc->addStyleSheetVersion($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/template.css');
```

This css file is for overrides later on or for later users to fix something they may not like that I have created.

```
$doc->addStyleSheetVersion($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/override.css');
```